# How to add a Default text on Drop Down List?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having a hard time adding a default text to a drop down list. 
I want to have a default "Select a department..." text to my drop down list. Where the text has no value at all and will never be add to the database when selected. It is just a display, like an instruction to a user.

---

```
void GetUserTypes()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TypeID, TypeName FROM Types";
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    ddlTypes.DataSource = dr;
    ddlTypes.DataTextField = "TypeName";
    ddlTypes.DataValueField = "TypeID";
    ddlTypes.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

---

```
    <!--Department-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-4">
            Department</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTypes" runat="server" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

I have tried adding a AppendDataBoundItems but the problem is when I submit the form having the selected item of the drop down list is "Select a department..." it will have an error.

Comment: Answer by Carlitrosss should address your need. It should be noted that setting `AppendDataBoundItems=True' ensures that your datasource items will be appended without removing the initial item added in the markup.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a ListItem directly in the mark up, such as:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlTypes" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select value..." Value="0" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Make sure AppendDataBoundItems="true" is present though.
And in your event listener or validation, check that dllTypes.SelectedValue != 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
ddlTypes.DataBind();
ddlType.Insert(0,new ListItem("","Select a department..."))
```

when you submit,you need to check the ddlType's value,just like

```
if(ddlType.SelectedIndex>0)
{
    //your code
}
```